how to reslove unsatisfyLinkError for libgdal.so file in 64-bit android
I am developing an Android app that uses the libgdal.so library. When I run the app I get the error like this

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
"/data/app/~~fEMejdDPZpV3FZzivEAV9Q==/com.example.myapplicationosmproject-zpD-GJjTpPYl-ZXHVm9m1g==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64/libgdal.so"
is 32-bit instead of 64-bit.
I tried the architecture typically included
armeabi-v7a
arm64-v8a
x86
x86_64

